# date conversion in csv to mysql db format

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

I am exporting a csv file in to mysql db using load data infile syntax.
the date in csv is in `2009/10/31  7:8:57.0` format. Is there any way to convert this while loading to something like `2009-10-31 07:08:57` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute `TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(datefromcsv, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS.FF'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS')` when you are doing the `INSERT` into the db.

Comment: thx for the info. I am using mysql and found that  STR_TO_DATE will do thr trick.

Comment: owh I thought MySql use the same `TO_DATE` function like oracle. sorry :P

Answer (score 0):

(usual caveats apply here) A regular expression might be what you need. Substitute / with - and remove the trailing .0. 
I am surprised, though, that mysql can't handle dates like the one you provided. See for example the [mySql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html). Have you tried feeding it to mysql and seeing what happens?